# How to split a Text node to sub Text node with specified length?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something similar to `splitText()`, but with length, so if I have a Text node that contains the following string for example:

```
Hello please get *me* as a text node
```

Then only get `*me*` as a new Text node.

`splitText()` just splits into two so that's not working

Comment: So you want to extract the string between the asterisks and create a new text node from that string, without changing the original text node?

Comment: *"...but with length"*: It is not clear what you want.

Comment: @kmoser yes exactly. trincot sorry, what I mean is to do something similar to `CharacterData.replaceData()`, where you have the `count` parameter to specify the length of the data to be replaced after the offset. So I was thinking about creating a new Text node with a `count` after the offset as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, which is more straight forward if you know you want to split on the asterisk.

```js
const textNode = document.body.firstChild
const text = textNode.data.split("*")[1]
const newTextNode = document.createTextNode(text)
document.querySelector("strong").append(newTextNode)
```

```html
Hello please get *me* as a text node
<br> new textNode: <strong><strong>
```

You can also use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

```js
const textNode = document.body.firstChild
const text = textNode.data.substring(22, 26)
const newTextNode = document.createTextNode(text)
document.querySelector("strong").append(newTextNode)
```

```html
Hello please get *me* as a text node
<br> new textNode: <strong><strong>
```

Comment: thank you, in my case I wanted the new node including the asterisks. I will have the starting of the string by a location index of the string (And not by a specific character)

Comment: @B.DLiroy, you can use substring if you want to operate on indicies. See my update.